# How can I compute the value of a cell in R based on values in surrounding rows?

Tags: r, vector

```
v1 = 1:20

# how to create v2 such that v2[i] = v1[i - 1] - 2 * v1[i] + v1[i + 1]?
```

I'm trying to compute a vector v2 whose values are computed from a window of values in v1. I tried rollingapply but that requires a vectorised function, not a heterogenous function like I have here. I'm thinking of a solution that would let something like `diff` be implemented.

I assume I need to use some sort of time series library.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, `accumulate2` can work

```
library(purrr)
accumulate2(v1, v1[-length(v1)], ~ ..1 - (2 * ..3) + ..2)[-1]
[1]    1    0   -2   -5   -9  -14  -20  -27  -35  -44  -54  -65  -77  -90 -104 -119 -135 -152 -170
```

-checking the output with a `for` loop

```
out <- numeric(length(v1)-1)
out[1] <- v1[1]
for(i in 2:(length(v1)-1)) out[i] <- out[i-1] - 2 *(v1[i]) + v1[i+1]
> out
 [1]    1    0   -2   -5   -9  -14  -20  -27  -35  -44  -54  -65  -77  -90 -104 -119 -135 -152 -170
```